# how to impliment delete and edit button in recyclerView using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

i am making a simple blog app using firebase as backend. in app i am showing comments list in post detail activity i want to implement edit and delete button in the front of every comment and want to visible it only if that comment write by the current user 
this is my postDetailActivity

where should i need to implement the delete button
plz... help me if u need any other info comment....

updated to FirbaseRecyclerView but now delete button not working

```
public  class PostDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "PostDetailActivity";

public static final String EXTRA_POST_KEY = "post_key";

private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
private DatabaseReference mCommentsReference;
private ValueEventListener mPostListener;

protected String mPostKey;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentViewHolder> mAdapter;

private ImageView postPic;
private TextView mTitleView;
private TextView mBodyView;
private EditText mCommentField;
private Button mCommentButton;
public  Button del_comment;
private RecyclerView mCommentsRecycler;
private LinearLayoutManager mlinearLayoutManager;
private String commentKey;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_detail);

    // Get post key from intent
    mPostKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_KEY);
    if (mPostKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_POST_KEY");
    }

    // Initialize Database
    mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("posts").child(mPostKey);
    mCommentsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("post-comments");

    // Initialize Views
   // mAuthorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);
    mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_title);
    mBodyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_body);
    postPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.form_details_image);
    mCommentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_comment_text);
    mCommentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_post_comment);
    del_comment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_comment);
    mCommentsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_comments);

    mCommentButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mCommentsRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    mCommentsRecycler.setLayoutManager(mlinearLayoutManager);

}

private Query getcommentQuery(DatabaseReference mCommentsReference) {
    return mCommentsReference.child(mPostKey);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Add value event listener to the post
    // [START post_value_event_listener]
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
           // mAuthorView.setText(post.author);
            mTitleView.setText(post.title);
            mBodyView.setText(post.body);
            final String formImage = String.valueOf(post.postDetailPic);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            if (formImage.length() > 0) {
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(formImage)
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .into(postPic, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                //Try again online if cache failed
                                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                        .load(formImage)
                                        //.error(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp)
                                        .into(postPic, new Callback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess() {

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError() {
                                                Log.v("Picasso","Could not fetch image");
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    // [END post_value_event_listener]

    // Keep copy of post listener so we can remove it when app stops
    mPostListener = postListener;


    // Listen for comments

    Query commentQuery = getcommentQuery(mCommentsReference);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentViewHolder>(Comment.class,R.layout.item_comment,
            CommentViewHolder.class, commentQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final CommentViewHolder viewHolder,final Comment model,final int position) {
            final  DatabaseReference commentRef = getRef(position);
             commentKey = commentRef.getKey();

            if (model.commenter_id.containsKey(gUid())){
                viewHolder.rm_comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     mCommentsReference.child(mPostKey).child(commentKey).removeValue();

                }
            });
        }
    };
    mCommentsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}





@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // Remove post value event listener
    if (mPostListener != null) {
        mPostReference.removeEventListener(mPostListener);
    }

    // Clean up comments listener
    mAdapter.cleanup();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.button_post_comment) {
        postComment();
    }
}


private void postComment() {
    FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert mUser != null;
    final String uid = mUser.getUid();
    final DatabaseReference commentDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
            commentDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get user information
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    String authorName = user.name;
                    String commentUserPic = user.ProfilePic;



                    // Create new comment object
                    String commentText = mCommentField.getText().toString();

                    HashMap<String, Object> dateCreated;
                    {

                        //Otherwise make a new object set to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                        dateCreated = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        dateCreated.put("timeStamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                    }
                    HashMap<String,Boolean> commenter_id ;
                    {
                        commenter_id = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                        commenter_id.put(getUid(),true);
                    }
                    Comment comment = new Comment(uid, authorName, commentText, commentUserPic, dateCreated, commenter_id);

                    // Push the comment, it will appear in the list
                    mCommentsReference.push().setValue(comment);


                    // Clear the field
                    mCommentField.setText(null);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}

private String getUid() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}






    private Context mContext;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private List<String> mCommentIds = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Comment> mComments = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mkey;



       // mContext = context;
      //  mDatabaseReference = ref;

        // Create child event listener
        // [START child_event_listener_recycler]
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                taskDeletion(dataSnapshot);
                // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                mkey = dataSnapshot.getKey();


                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // Update RecyclerView
                mCommentIds.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mComments.add(comment);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mComments.size() - 1);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
                // comment and if so displayed the changed comment.
                Comment newComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                int commentIndex = mCommentIds.indexOf(commentKey);
                if (commentIndex > -1) {
                    // Replace with the new data
                    mComments.set(commentIndex, newComment);

                    // Update the RecyclerView
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(commentIndex);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onChildChanged:unknown_child:" + commentKey);
                }
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
                // comment and if so remove it.
                String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();


                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                int commentIndex = mCommentIds.indexOf(commentKey);
                if (commentIndex > -1) {
                    // Remove data from the list
                    mCommentIds.remove(commentIndex);
                    mComments.remove(commentIndex);

                    // Update the RecyclerView
                   mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(commentIndex);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onChildRemoved:unknown_child:" + commentKey);
                }
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A comment has changed position, use the key to determine if we are
                // displaying this comment and if so move it.
                Comment movedComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                // ...

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("PostDetailActivity", "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load comments.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        };

  // ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        // [END child_event_listener_recycler]

        // Store reference to listener so it can be removed on app stop
   //     mChildEventListener = childEventListener;


    private String gUid() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }



    }
```

Comment: Honestly look into the `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` which is part of Firebase UI. It should handle delete and edit actions for you.

Comment: but my my comments recyclerView don't have FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter it have simple RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: Yes that's why I'm not posting this as an answer. I'm suggesting that you use the `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` because it was designed to handle data coming from the Realtime Database, it will make your life much easier. Otherwise you essentially need to do what they are doing which turns your simple `RecyclerView.Adapter` into a not so simple one.

Comment: ok i find the problem i have null point exception  error at Query i solved it now it showing the list but delete button not working.....now...see above code is updated....

Comment: and comment list also not updating....

Comment: okk i done it the delete button working now